# VS 2010 Update interface references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, interface

Is there any way in VS 2010 to auto update classes referencing an Interface?
Say i add a parameter to Export, is there any function that will update all my referencing interfaces?

```
public interface IStateExporter
{
    void Export();
}
```

to

```
public interface IStateExporter
{
    void Export(string path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Refactor context menu lets you remove and re-order parameters and will update all implementations of the interface.  But, the best VS2010 can offer when adding a parameter is the ability to automatically implement the updated member with a new method that throws NotImplementedException.

I know CodeRush/Refactor Pro from DevExpress has a function that walks you through adding/changing parameters and visiting each implementer to let you add the parameter.  I imagine ReSharper has the same feature, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way that you are thinking if I understand you correctly.

What you can do is go to the inheritance declaration, and use the auto implement feature to save a little time.

So for example, put the cursor over IStateExporter in the line

```
public class ContreteStateExporter : IStateExporter
```

and hit CTRL + .   (Control plus period) and choose to implement the interface. Then, you can copy paste the code from the previous method. Still, extremely messy, but I suppose it would save you a little time.

Answer (score 0):

Went out searching some more, Resharper does exactly what I am asking.
Not only from the interface but you can also change the implementationa dn ask it to update the interface and all references.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper worked perfect.

Added my new param to the implementation, and little icon popped up, asked me if i would like to update the interface and the other implementations, clicked yes. Bam, all of the m and the interface(same signature) all have the param now.